# Correct Use Of Claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity

In a user's claims principal identity, I'm storing the classIDs that they have been assigned.
To achieve this, I'm having 1 instance of the "ClassID" custom claim type per classID that the user has access to (Rather than doing some kind of json serialization and stored them all in a single claim for example).

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClassID", 1));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClassID", 2));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClassID", 3));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClassID", 4));
```

Is this an appropriate and correct way to use claims?

The reason I'm doing this is to avoid a hit to the database every time I need to perform an authorization check, based on the classID

Comment: If you want to add if the user is authenticated then just use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,May you can add a sample of your code to make me understand you

Comment: @AmroMustafa No that's not what I'm trying to do.
I'm adding several claims to the users claims collection and asking if it's the correct thing to do (I've updated my question to clarify somewhat.)